# Javascript to do list localStorage

Tags: javascript, list, local-storage

I am making a to do list for my assignment and I am struggling with local storage and have researched and watched a ton of videos and still cannot figure it out. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?

```
const form = document.querySelector('#toDoForm');
const input = document.querySelector('#addTask');
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const liItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (let li of liItems) {
  const liBtn = document.createElement('button');
  liBtn.innerText = '\u2716';
  li.appendChild(liBtn);
}
ul.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
  if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    e.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newToDo = document.createElement('li');
  const btns = document.createElement('button');
  btns.innerText = '\u2716';
  newToDo.innerText = input.value;
  newToDo.appendChild(btns);
  ul.appendChild(newToDo);
  input.value = '';
});
//local storage
function saveToDos() {
  localStorage.setItem('taskList', ul.innerHTML);
}

function savedToDos() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('tasklist')) {
    ul.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('tasklist');
    clearTodos();
  }
}

function clearTodos() {
  ul.innerHTML = '';
  localStorage.removeItem('tasklist', ul.innerHTML);
}
clearTodos();
savedToDos();
```

Comment: Note you used `taskList` in one call and `tasklist` in the others. The keys are case sensitive

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the specific problem and or error? We need you to also learn [ask] and provide enough information about what you need this code to do, what  is or isn't working and narrow down where you are having problems

Comment: Thanks Patrick I did not catch that. And thanks for the welcome! When I go into my console and try to find the list items I am trying to store, they are not there and in general they are not saving at all.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the three things below, I confirmed that the code works.

1. Fix a typo: "taskList" -> "tasklist"
2. Delete `clearTodos()`
3. Add to call `saveToDos()` when adding/deleting a task.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <form id="toDoForm">
      <label for="fname">Add Task:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="addTask" name="addTask" value=""><br>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <script>
      const form = document.querySelector('#toDoForm');
      const input = document.querySelector('#addTask');
      const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
      const liItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
      for (let li of liItems) {
        const liBtn = document.createElement('button');
        liBtn.innerText = '\u2716';
        li.appendChild(liBtn);
      }
      ul.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
          e.target.parentElement.remove();
          saveToDos();
        }
        if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
          e.target.classList.toggle('checked');
        }
      }, false);
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newToDo = document.createElement('li');
        const btns = document.createElement('button');
        btns.innerText = '\u2716';
        newToDo.innerText = input.value;
        newToDo.appendChild(btns);
        ul.appendChild(newToDo);
        input.value = '';
        saveToDos();
      });
      //local storage
      function saveToDos() {
        localStorage.setItem('tasklist', ul.innerHTML);
      }

      function savedToDos() {
        console.log('savedTodos!')
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('tasklist'))
        if (localStorage.getItem('tasklist')) {
          console.log('savedTodos!!')
          ul.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('tasklist');
        }
      }

      savedToDos();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This whole time I have been pulling hair trying to get this to work! Thanks so much!!